# determine how a linux process was invoked

Tags: linux, process

Is there a way in linux, to determine how a process was invoked?
I know, that `ps` displays the startup parameters, but I'm interested how the process start was executed.

Was it a `init.d` script, a `cron job` or manual invocation via cli.
Right now I am looking through all configs/commands manually, is there an easy way I am overlooking?

(I also know, that the presence of `systemd` etc. is distro related which helps to priorize a little bit.)

Comment: Why do you ask, and what is the concrete use case? Even huge programs like the Firefox browser can be started from the menu or from a terminal...

Comment: concret use case is, that I got a server from my colleague, and I want to understand how he did the setup. Since the whole OS is outdated and has to be exchanged I try to save all relevant config files so one can easiely redeploy everything.
However, this usually occurs to me with different distros and different services, so I was wondering whether there is a global command or something like this - probably exchanging the service binary to log everything and rebooting will work as you explained...

Comment: In practice backup (on external media) the `/etc/` file tree

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, for a process of pid 1234, you can get valuable information about it thru `/proc/1234/` (see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details)

See also [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [*Linux From Scratch*](http://linuxfromscratch.org/)

For exemple, try `ps $$` then `cat /proc/$$/status` then `cat /proc/$$/maps` then `cat /proc/$$/comm` in your terminal (running probably the [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) shell, or [zsh](https://zsh.org/))

Consider writing your C program doing appropriate [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (with perhaps [opendir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) and [readdir(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)...) to query that information from `/proc/` ....

Remember to read [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). A lot of functions (like [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [getpwnam(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html) ....) can fail.

Download, then study for inspiration the source code of the [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) shell (or even of the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/)), it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).